# Map from-to using react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a map loop that returns a list of values eg 0 - 100. The problem is that this will return the whole list. I want to only return a specific number of values. eg (11-20). What would be the best way of implementing this?

The current code is

```
const all = this.props.memories.map((value, index) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {value}
                </div>
            )
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.slice()` as `this.props.memories.slice(11, 20).map...`

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Slice ..Use it when you do not want to alter the original contents, instead a shallow copy of that for local change and usage.

```
this.props.memories.slice(11,20).map((value, index) => {
    return (
        <div>{value}</div>
    )
})
```